# $(...).parentElement is not a function - WebDriver IO / TypeScript issue

Tags: typescript, webdriver-io

Okay, the aim is simple. I need to go up from root to catch its parent and from webdriver documentation it should look like that more less:

```
it('should get class from parent element', async () => {
 const elem = await $$('p');
 const parent = await elem[2].parentElement();
 console.log(await parent.getAttribute('class'));  // outputs: "parent"
});
```

In my case where I'm using sync version, it looks like that

```
    public isErrorDisplayed(): boolean {
      const parent = browser.call(async () => {
        return await $(this.root).parentElement();
    });

     return parent.getAttribute("class").includes("Mui-error");
    }
```

I had to wrap `parentElement()` cause the compiler claimed that it will return `Promise<WebDriver.IO>` which would be fine if it wasn't in the `@wdio/sync` mode! So no `async/await` should be necessary.

I applied "workaround" and then it says that:

`$(...).parentElement is not a function`

which is actually seen and proposed by vs-code.

Using `node 14.17.1` which should support `@wdio/sync` mode and supports clearly with the rest of the code : )

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would be seeing this issue,

There is an easy shorthand alternative for getting the parent using xpaths though

```
const elem = await $$('p');
const parent = await elem[2].$('..');
```

Comment: yeah, I made it like that, but it's still pretty weird why such easy function is not working the way it's described in documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
describe('My Login application', () => {
    it('should login with valid credentials', async () => {
        await browser.url('https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/login');

        await $('#username').parentElement();
    });
});
```

The document is for async , v7 the above code works as expected for sync you dont need await

```
it('should get class from parent element', () => {
    const elem = $$('p');
    const parent = elem[2].parentElement()
    console.log(parent.getAttribute('class')); // outputs: "parent"
});
```

.